# convert docker-compose.yml file to kubernetes

Tags: docker, tomcat, kubernetes, kompose

I am converting a docker-compose file to kubernetes using kompose running the follwing command:

$kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes_image.yaml

After the command finish the ouput is the following.

```
WARN Volume mount on the host "/usr/docker/adpater/dbdata" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
INFO Network integration is detected at Source, shall be converted to equivalent NetworkPolicy at Destination
WARN Volume mount on the host "/usr/docker/adpater/license.json" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
WARN Volume mount on the host "/usr/docker/adpater/certificates/ssl.crt" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
WARN Volume mount on the host "/usr/docker/adpater/certificates/ssl.key" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
WARN Volume mount on the host "/usr/docker/adpater/server.xml" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
INFO Network integration is detected at Source, shall be converted to equivalent NetworkPolicy at Destination
```

To push the converted file to kubernetes I run the follwoing command:

$kubectl apply -f kubernetes_image.yaml

```
NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-557dd849c8-bsdq7    1/1     Running            1          17h
tomcat-7cd65d4556-spjbl   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   76         18h
```

if I run: 
$ kubectl describe pod tomcat-7cd65d4556-spjbl
I get the following message:

```
Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
      Message:      OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/usr/docker/adapter/server.xml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a6df90a0ef4cbe8b2a3fa5352be5f304cd7b648fb1381492308f0a7fceb931cc/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a6df90a0ef4cbe8b2a3fa5352be5f304cd7b648fb1381492308f0a7fceb931cc/merged/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
      Exit Code:    127
      Started:      Sun, 31 May 2020 13:35:00 +0100
      Finished:     Sun, 31 May 2020 13:35:00 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  75
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /run/secrets/rji_license.json from tomcat-hostpath0 (rw)
      /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml from tomcat-hostpath3 (rw)
      /usr/local/tomcat/conf/ssl.crt from tomcat-hostpath1 (rw)
      /usr/local/tomcat/conf/ssl.key from tomcat-hostpath2 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-8dhnk (ro)
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

---

```
version: '3.6'

networks:
  integration:

services:
  mysql:
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: 'integrationdb'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    image: db:poc
    networks:
    - integration
    ports:
    - '3306:3306'
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  tomcat:
    image: adapter:poc
    networks:
    - integration
    ports:
    - '8080:8080'
    - '8443:8443'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./license.json:/run/secrets/rji_license.json
      - ./certificates/ssl.crt:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/ssl.crt
      - ./certificates/ssl.key:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/ssl.key
      - ./server.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

Versions of the tools:

```
kompose: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)

docker: 19.03.9

kubectl:Major:"1", Minor:"18"
```

I think my challange here is whithin this type of volumes or files, I dont know how can I migrate or convert them to kubernetes and put the tomcat pod running fine.
Could someone give me a hand?

```
 volumes:
          - ./license.json:/run/secrets/rji_license.json
          - ./certificates/ssl.crt:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/ssl.crt
          - ./certificates/ssl.key:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/ssl.key
          - ./server.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

When Kompose warns you:

```
WARN Volume mount on the host "/usr/docker/adpater/license.json" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
```

It means that it can't translate this fragment of the `docker-compose.yml` file into Kubernetes syntax:

```yaml
volumes:
    - ./license.json:/run/secrets/rji_license.json
```

In native Kubernetes, you'd need to provide this content in ConfigMap or Secret objects, and then [mount the file into the pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap).  You can't directly access content on the system from which you're launching the containers.

You can't really get around directly working with the Kubernetes YAML files here.  You could run [`kompose convert`](https://kompose.io/user-guide/#kompose-convert) to generate the skeleton files, but then you'll need to edit those to add the ConfigMaps, PersistentVolumeClaims (for the database storage), and relevant volume and mount declarations, and then run `kubectl apply -f` to actually run them.  I'd check the Kubernetes YAML files into source control, and maintain them in parallel with your Docker Compose setup.

Comment: cheers David, thanks for the reply but do u have just an example for a case like this: ./license.json:/run/secrets/rji_license.json

Answer (score -1):

[Move2Kube](https://github.com/konveyor/move2kube) (which does support docker-compose translation), can handle this case and tries to convert the volumes by interacting with you.

```
    ? 6. [] What type of container registry login do you want to use?
Hints:
 [Docker login from config mode, will use the default config from your local machine.]
 No authentication
? 7. Do you want to create PVC for host path [/Users/ashok/wksps/hc/temp/test2/src/dbdata]?:
Hints:
 [Use PVC for persistent storage wherever applicable]
 Yes
? 8. Do you want to create PVC for host path [/Users/ashok/wksps/hc/temp/test2/src/license.json]?:
Hints:
 [Use PVC for persistent storage wherever applicable]
 No
? 9. Do you want to create PVC for host path [/Users/ashok/wksps/hc/temp/test2/src/certificates/ssl.crt]?:
Hints:
 [Use PVC for persistent storage wherever applicable]
 No
? 10. Do you want to create PVC for host path [/Users/ashok/wksps/hc/temp/test2/src/certificates/ssl.key]?:
Hints:
 [Use PVC for persistent storage wherever applicable]
 No
? 11. Do you want to create PVC for host path [/Users/ashok/wksps/hc/temp/test2/src/server.xml]?:
Hints:
 [Use PVC for persistent storage wherever applicable]
 No
? 12. Which storage class to use for persistent volume claim [vol17655897939759777588] used by [mysql]
Hints:
 [If you have a custom cluster, you can use collect to get storage classes from it.]
 default
? 13. Provide the ingress host domain
Hints:
 [Ingress host domain is part of service URL]
 myproject.com
? 14. Provide the TLS secret for ingress
Hints:
 [Enter TLS secret name]
```

If the above choices were made Move2Kube creates the following artifacts:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    move2kube.konveyor.io/service.expose: "true"
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    move2kube.konveyor.io/network/integration: "true"
    move2kube.konveyor.io/service: tomcat
  name: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      move2kube.konveyor.io/service: tomcat
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        move2kube.konveyor.io/service.expose: "true"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        move2kube.konveyor.io/network/integration: "true"
        move2kube.konveyor.io/service: tomcat
      name: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: adapter:poc
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: tomcat
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /run/secrets/rji_license.json
              name: vol16871681589659214643
            - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/ssl.crt
              name: vol12635587774184387470
            - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/ssl.key
              name: vol7446232639477381794
            - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
              name: vol4920239289720818926
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /Users/ashok/wksps/hc/temp/test2/src/license.json
          name: vol16871681589659214643
        - hostPath:
            path: /Users/ashok/wksps/hc/temp/test2/src/certificates/ssl.crt
          name: vol12635587774184387470
        - hostPath:
            path: /Users/ashok/wksps/hc/temp/test2/src/certificates/ssl.key
          name: vol7446232639477381794
        - hostPath:
            path: /Users/ashok/wksps/hc/temp/test2/src/server.xml
          name: vol4920239289720818926
    status: {}
```

and

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    move2kube.konveyor.io/service.expose: "true"
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    move2kube.konveyor.io/network/integration: "true"
    move2kube.konveyor.io/service: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      move2kube.konveyor.io/service: mysql
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        move2kube.konveyor.io/service.expose: "true"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        move2kube.konveyor.io/network/integration: "true"
        move2kube.konveyor.io/service: mysql
      name: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              value: integrationdb
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              value: password
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: password
          image: db:poc
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: mysql
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              protocol: TCP
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
              name: vol17655897939759777588
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: vol17655897939759777588
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: vol17655897939759777588
status: {}
```

and

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: vol17655897939759777588
spec:
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
  storageClassName: default
  volumeName: vol17655897939759777588
status: {}
```

Essentially depending on your choice Move2Kube will create the appropriate artifacts for you.

You can check out how it works in https://konveyor.github.io/move2kube/tutorials/docker-compose/.