# minikube - kompose up --> WARN Volume mount on the host "/home/robin/Dokumente/Blacklisting_Ult/db_data" isn't supported?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, cluster-computing, minikube

So, I want to use `kompose up` on my docker-compose.yml which looks like this:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    env_file: 
      - ./env/env_vars.env
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

But every time I do this, it returns

```
WARN Volume mount on the host "/home/test/Documents/test_pj/db_data" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
```

What can I do to this?

Comment: You need to move that database setup script into a Kubernetes ConfigMap.  Kompose can't do this on its own.

Comment: And how do I do this? @DavidMaze

Comment: [The last time I researched this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62116048/10008173) I recommended using `kompose convert` to generate YAML, checking it in, and adding the ConfigMap details.  The Kubernetes documentation describes configuration to [Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).